# node js post request only works second time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, command-line-interface

I have one strange issue, when I submit form, it redirects to form action URL then it shows blank page. When I reload it again it will display the data.

**index.jade** - `http://172.18.0.60:3000/`

```
  form#command(action='runcommand', method='post')
    input#cmdls(type='checkbox', name='cmdls', value='ls -la')
    label(for='cmdls') List Files
    br
    input#cmdpwd(type='checkbox', name='cmdpwd', value='pwd')
    label(for='cmdpwd') Print Working Directory
    br
    input#cmddate(type='checkbox', name='cmddate', value='date')
    label(for='cmddate') Date
    br
    input.button(type='submit', value='Run')
```

**app.js**

```
var tmp=""; 
app.post('/runcommand',function(req,res){

    for (var key in req.body) {

            console.log(key);
            function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
            exec(req.body[key], function(error, stdout, stderr) {
              if (!error) {
                    tmp+=stdout;                       
              } else {
                tmp+=stderr;
              }
            });

    }

    res.render("result",{ data: tmp });

});
```

**result.jade** - `http://172.18.0.60:3000/runcommand`

extends layout

```
block content
    h1= "Result"   
    pre=  data
```

When I submit form it will redirect to `http://172.18.0.60:3000/runcommand` only displaying h1, when I reload it again it display **data**.

why it is behave like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec()` is asynchronous so it finishes AFTER you call `res.render()`.  So, you need to render only after all the `exec()` calls have finsished.  This would probably be easier to code if you used promises and `Promise.all()` to keep track of when all the `exec()` calls were done, but you could also use a counter to know when the last one was done.

Here's a scheme using a counter:

```
app.post('/runcommand', function(req, res) {

    let keys = Object.keys(req.body);
    let cnt = 0;
    let tmp = '';
    if (!keys.length) {
        // render something when there were no keys
        res.render(...)
    } else {
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            console.log(key);

            exec(req.body[key], function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                if (!error) {
                    tmp += stdout;
                } else {
                    tmp += stderr;
                }
                ++cnt;
                // if all exec calls have finished, the render
                if (cnt === keys.length) {
                    res.render("result", {data:tmp});
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

P.S. This code looks like it allows any client to run any arbitray program on the server (if it's in the path or they can construct the full path).  That seems very dangerous.

P.P.S.  Accumulating `tmp` outside the handler like you were doing in your original code is a disaster for multiple users using your server as multiple requests can tromp on either other's value in `tmp`.  Accumulated data like this needs to either be in a local variable inside the request handler or in a property on the request object so that it can never conflict with other requests in process.

Comment: Great! explanation.